# Iterating over an existing list of questions and providing an answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

In my app, a `call_for_submission` has_many `questions`. I want users who are making an `submission` to see each `question`, and be able to provide an `answer`. So a `question` has_one `answer`, and a `submission` has_many `answers`.

How can I iterate through a `call_for_application's` `questions` in the `submission` edit view, and provide form fields for an `answer`? I've got as far as this in the `submission` edit view, using `cocoon` for the dynamic fields:

```
= simple_form_for @submission do |f|
    #... other code

    - @questions.each do |question|
      = question.question_text
      = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |answer|
        = render 'answer_fields', :f => answer
      %p
        .links
          = link_to_add_association('<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add answer'.html_safe, f, :answers)
```

But I can't figure out what the associations should be. Does an `answer` belong_to a `submission` and a `question`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I think your relations are wrong.

I'd remove the relation between `answers` and `questions`, and introduce a relation between `submissons` and `questions` instead.

```
# submission.rb
has_many :questions

# question.rb
belongs_to :submission
```

For the nested-form part, have a look at this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

In fact, even the topic and relation setup is similar to your case.